# QR Code Decoder, address issue of variables

Tags: java, android, qr-code

How would I be able to call a string from one activity to another?
My code isn't working, I am trying to achieve a program that can browse
the images on the SD card of my phone and return the address of the image.
I am developing a QR Code decoder based on the zxing library.

```
 private void onFileClick(Option o)
{
    //Toast.makeText(this, "File Clicked: "+o.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Toast.makeText(this, "File Clicked: "+o.getPath(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    QRDecoder qr = null;
    str = o.getPath();
    qr.setFile(str);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, QRDecoder.class);
    Log.d("filter", str);
    Log.d("filter", qr.my_url);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

before calling startActivity
`intent.putExtra("path", str);`

in onCreate of the QRDecoder

`String path = getIntent().getStringExtra("path");`